# Laravel 4 self relationship nested routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, nested-resources

I'm starting with laravel and I need to do something like this
`localhost/diretory1/directory2/directory3`

Is is possible to set this up like a nested route? At the moment its working like this 
`localhost/directory1` -> `localhost/directory2`

Comment: Should the directory names be dynamic or static?

Comment: They are dynamic, user can name them whatever they want.

Comment: Ok. Is 3 levels the maximum or are there an infinite number of levels?

Comment: In theory 4 would be the maximum, but I dont whant to have problems in the future so I guess I have to say its and infinite number of levels

Comment: Alright. Give me some time, I'll write an answer later today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is define one slug route that catches all requests. (Make sure that you define other routes above that one route so the request ends only up in the slug route if nothing else matches)

```
Route::any('{slug}', function($slug){
    $directories = explode('/', $slug);

    // lookup the directory(ies) in the db, file system, etc 

    if(!$exists){
        // when the directories don't exists, it's probably appropriate to throw a 404 Not found error.
        App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

What you do in the route function (or a controller if it gets too much code to live in the routes.php) is up to you. I don't know how your application works so I can't help you with that.